# JQuery showing too many decimals

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-progressbar

I have this code for a progress bar but the `.progress-label`is showing too many decimals, something like (2.020302032400%).

My code looks like this

```
<script>     
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#progressbar").progressbar({
         value: 1 
     });
 $("#progressbar > .ui-progressbar-value").animate({
         width: "37%"            
     }, {
       step: function(width){
         $('.progress-label').text(width + '%'); }
       }, 2000);

 });

 </script>
```

How can I get rid of the decimals?, also, is it possible to have the percentage grows by one?, right now it's going too fast.

-----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

With Barmar answer I completed the code, if someone needs the solution here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
         value: 1 
  });
$("#progressbar > .ui-progressbar-value").animate({
         width: "37%"            
}, {
duration: 10000,
step: function (width){
    $('.progress-label').text(width.toFixed(0) + "%");
      }
});
});
```

Comment: `Math.round(width);` or perhaps you want to keep a couple decimal places `Math.round(width * 100) / 100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `toFixed()` method to specify the number of decimal places.

```
$('.progress-label').text(width.toFixed(1) + '%'); }
```

will display 1 digit after the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! One  thing, I don't think the 2000 timing is working at all on that code, do you have any idea of why is that happening?

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/animate/, the arguments to `.animate()` are either `(properties, duration, easing, complete)` or `(properties, options)`. It doesn't look like you can supply `duration` as a separate argument when giving options, you should use the `duration:` option.

Comment: Never mind, I just have it fixed, I updated my code on top just in case.

Comment: Yes I used the duration option. Thanks Barmar!

Comment: Sorry Barmar, any ideas of how can I implement this code but for multiple bars? having the $('#progressbar').data("id") value for example?

Comment: `$("#id1").progressbar({ options });`, `$("#id2").progressbar({ options });` and so on.

Comment: Yep I did like that and it works perfectly but I was meaning to do it dynamically, geting the width value from a data-width="xx%" or something like that and having one script and not one for each bar.

Comment: You should be able to do that with `.each()` and `$(this).data("width")`.

Comment: `$(this) + $(".ui-progressbar-value")` makes no sense, it should be `$(".ui-progressbar-value", $(this))`. Further discussion of this should be in a new question, SO is complaining about extended discussion in comments.